# Mock/practice trading for options (delta/gamma hedging etc.)

Tags: options, delta-hedging

I know there are some sites for practicing equity investing. But could you provide me with suggestions concerning options trading etc. I read Natenbergs book on Options and want to test  things like delta and gamma hedging in real life, without risking money yet.

Comment: Check out ThinkOrSwim's paperMoney.